# jQuery UI Tooltip and Colorbox

Tags: jquery, tooltip, lightbox, colorbox

I've got a little application where I use jQuery UI's Tooltip function and Colorbox.
You can find it [here](http://www.mymobisite.be/victorpeeters)

When I go with the mouse over the wordmap (now only Rioolreiniging and Rioolinspectie), the tooltip appears fine, as it should do.

When clicking on the word, there should open a Lightbox (Colorbox) with the text of all tooltips. Works fine too.

But when i close the Colorbox, the Tooltip stays... How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Colorbox has the event "onClosed". You have to call:

```
$('MY_ID').colorBox({ onClosed: function(){ 
    $( ".selector" ).tooltip( "close" ); } 
})
```

Comment: Really thanks. I already tried something similar (destroy and then create the tooltip again), but didn't work.
Thank you very much!

Comment: it should be the "event".. not the "even" i guess :-)

Comment: will not work for me also... (i'm having same issue)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
$('MY_ID').colorBox({
    onOpen: function() {
        $("#tt").tooltip("disable");
    },
    onClosed: function() {
        $("#tt").tooltip("enable");
    }
});
```

With the above answer it will close the tooltip after the colorbox disappears but the tooltip won't work anymore afterwards.